# sturct intitiatlization according to user input:

Tags: c++

My Question is how do I ask the user How many employees they have and how do I use that integer in the loop in this case I have used 10 as a constant.

ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>


using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int employeeid;;
};


void InputData (Employee i[]);
void checkdata(Employee i[]);

void Results (Employee i[]);



int main()
{   

   Employee i[10];



   checkdata (i);
   Results (i);

   cin.get();cin.get();
   return 0;
 }

 void InputData (Employee i[])
{
 for (int x=0; x < 10; x++)
        {
             this is where the loop resides and runs 10 times

       }
}
Void checkdata (i);
{
}
Void Results (i);
{
}
```

Also is there any way I can make sure employeeid is not a duplicate of previous entries ?

Thanks for taking your time to help me with this.

Comment: I just used not x for the loop and it worked thanks for the help Scott Hunter

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the previous entries & check each one.

Comment: How do you do that using a loop though ? I could use an other for loop to try and look for it but it would look at itself and say its a match  so should I use x-1 ?

Comment: If you have already put the new one in the array, then yes, only search up to (but not including) its index; if you haven't put it in yet, then it isn't an issue.

Comment: thanks, I think it works but it only looks for the one before with that so if value 1 and value 10 are same its not going to see it matched.

Comment: for (int x=0; x < 10; x++)
   {
    
  
   cout << "Please Enter " << x+1 << "    employeet ID: ";
   cin >> i[x].employeeid; 
   if (!cin) throw 3;
   for (int x=0; x < 10; x++)
   {if (i[x].employeeid == i[x-1].employeeid) throw 2;}
   if (!cin) throw 3;

Comment: Don't use `x` for the index variable in the inner loop; only have that loop go until it is `< x`; compare each item to `i[x]`.